# Navigation bar is not properly lined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a web project using HTML, CSS and JS. Right now, two tabs of my navigation bar are not aligned properly. How can I fix this?

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
ul {
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width:900px;
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px tahoma;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  border:black 1px;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: yellow;
  color: yellow;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden; 
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: orange; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: yellow; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#new_div{
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul id="nan"><span></span>
        <li><a href="#">About 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Certifications</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foods</a>
      <ul id="nan"><span></span>
        <li><a href="#">Indian</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chinese</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Japanese</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thai</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Beverages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Deserts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gift Vo.</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is just simply add `display:inline;` with some paddings, for an example:

```
ul {
  text-align: left; 
  display: inline;  //modification
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0; //modification
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width:900px;
}
```

This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roLx5n3p/)

Comment: oh, i missed that.Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean is the navigation "Promotions" and "Gift Vo" is not in same line;
Because you set the "ul" width "900px",you can change the width or "ul li" padding to put down all navigation;

Comment: sorry,don't see you has been resovled;

Comment: yes, that's what i want.but i figured out that.Thanks for the response